# Applying OTB mean shift smoothing to a folder of rasters using Python 2

Tags: python-2.7, osgeo4w, otb-applications

I am very new to Python, and am having trouble coming up with a loop script that will allow me to apply a smoothing process to a folder of rasters. This is the script I am using for a single file right now:

```
import otbApplication

MeanShiftSmoothing = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("MeanShiftSmoothing")

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterString("in", "C:/Users/riddella/Desktop/Raster_Clip.tif")

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterString("fout", "C:/Users/riddella/Desktop/Raster_Clip_Smooth.tif")

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterInt("spatialr", 4)

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterFloat("ranger", 256)

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterFloat("thres", 0.1)

MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterInt("maxiter", 100)

MeanShiftSmoothing.ExecuteAndWriteOutput()
```

How can I reconstruct this script to read files from a folder, rather than just giving it a single file input and output? Apologies for my lack of base knowledge of Python, I only started working with it this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work. It assumes all your input files are in a same folder and the corresponding output files are written to separate folder.

```
from glob import glob
import os

import otbApplication

data_dir = '/path/to/data/dir'
output_dir = '/path/to/output/dir'

# Get list of input files
file_list = glob(os.path.join(data_dir, '*.tif'))

for file in file_list:
    # Build outpu filename
    filename_components = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))
    file_out = os.path.join(output_dir, filename_components[0] + '_smooth' + filename_components[1])

    MeanShiftSmoothing = otbApplication.Registry.CreateApplication("MeanShiftSmoothing")
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterString("in", file)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterString("fout", file_out)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterInt("spatialr", 4)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterFloat("ranger", 256)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterFloat("thres", 0.1)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.SetParameterInt("maxiter", 100)
    MeanShiftSmoothing.ExecuteAndWriteOutput()
```

Comment: Thank you, Loïc. I was able to resolve the issue outside of the board, but this looks similar to the code that worked.